# Do $\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb R^2$ have the same uniform structure?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, uniform-spaces

The hyperbolic upper half plane $\Bbb H$ and euclidean space $\Bbb R^2$ are not isomorphic as metric spaces, which can be see from the fact that in $\Bbb R^2$ for any point not on a geodesic there exists exactly one geodesic going through that point that does not intersect the original geodsic, whereas in $\Bbb H$ there exist infinitely many such geodesics.

I cannot see any such argument that uses information visible to the uniform structure however.

> Are $\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb R^2$ isomorphic as uniform spaces?

Comment: Why are you comparing $\Bbb H$ to $\Bbb R^2$ rather than $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. $\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb R^4$ are not the same even as topological spaces. With $\Bbb H$ I mean the upper half plane.

Comment: Also, when you talk about the "uniform structure", it seems to me that you're effectively talking about the topological structure on the space.  Am I missing something there?  Can topological spaces be non-homeomorphic with a common "uniform structure"?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. $\Bbb H$ is sometimes used for the quaternions.

Comment: No, a uniform structure induces a topological structure. But there is not a unique uniform structure for each topological space. For example $(0,1)$ has exactly $3$ uniform structures, one is induced by the usual metric, the other by metric $(0,\infty)$ and the other by $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: okay... so it stands to reason, if I understood correctly, that two spaces which are topologically distinct cannot come from the same uniform structure.  Is that right, or can different uniform structures induce the same topology?

Comment: Also, what are the geodesics in $\Bbb H$ if not the Euclidean lines?

Comment: In your comment you have two different statements. Topologically distinct spaces cannot have the same uniform structure (provided the uniform structure is compatible with the topology). Two different uniform spaces can be the same topological space, however.

Comment: For the geometry of $\Bbb H$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_half-plane_model

Comment: all right, thanks for humoring me.  I guess I'm out of my element here.

Comment: I suspect there is some flavor of invariant of uniform spaces involving their "ideal boundary", which differs for these two surfaces.

Comment: When you say the upper half plane, I am thinking you mean to use the metric that makes it the hyperbolic plane?  The hyperbolic metric would give you different geodesics, so that is my guess.  But of course you should say so in the question.

Comment: @GEdgar ok, I have put it into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As uniform spaces, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}$ are not isomorphic.

One way to prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}$ are not isomorphic as metric spaces is that the area of a disk grows quadratically with the radius in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but grows exponentially with the radius in $\mathbb{H}$. It is possible to make a similar argument using just the uniform structure.

First we define approximate notions of distance and volume for an arbitrary uniform space. Let $X$ be a uniform space, $U\subset X\times X$ an entourage. For $x$, $y\in X$, define
$$
d_U(x,y):=\inf\big\{n\big|\exists x_0,\ldots,x_n\in X: x_0=x,x_n=y, (x_i,x_{i+1})\in U\,\forall i\big\}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\cup\{+\infty\}.
$$
For $A\subset X$, we define
$$
\mu_U(A):=\sup\big\{n\big|\exists x_1,\ldots,x_n\in A:(x_i,x_j)\not\in U\,\forall i\neq j\big\}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\cup\{+\infty\}.
$$

Now we can prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}$ are not isomorphic as uniform spaces. For $\epsilon>0$, define an entourage $U_\epsilon:=\{(x,y):d(x,y)<\epsilon\}\subset(\mathbb{R}^2)^2$. We similarly define $V_\epsilon\subset\mathbb{H}^2$. For every $\epsilon>0$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mu_{U_\epsilon}\big(\{x:d_{U_\epsilon}(x,x_0)<n\}\big)}{n^2} <\infty.
$$
The sets $U_\epsilon$ form a fundamental system of entourages for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Claim**: For every entourage $U\subset V_1$ on $\mathbb{H}$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mu_{U}\big(\{x:d_{U}(x,x_0)<n\}\big)}{n^2}=\infty.
$$
**Proof**: The set $\{V_\epsilon\}$ is a fundamental system of entourages, so there must be some $\epsilon$ for which $V_\epsilon\subset U$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu_{U}\big(\{x:d_U(x,x_0)<n\}\big)}{n^2}&\geq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu_{V_1}\big(\{x:d_{V_\epsilon}(x,x_0)<n\}\big)}{n^2}\\
&\geq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu\big(B_{n\epsilon}(x_0)\big)/\mu(B_1(x_0))}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{\epsilon^2}{\mu(B_1(x_0))}\limsup_{m\to\infty}\frac{B_m(x_0)}{m^2}=\infty.
\end{align*}
$$
On the last line, the $\mu$ without subscript denotes ordinary measure on $\mathbb{H}$, and $B_r(p)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $p$. We used the fact that $\mu_{V_1}(A)\geq \mu(A)/\mu(B_1(x_0))$ for every set $A\subset\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: For the definition of $\mu_U(A)$ you want $x_1,..,x_n\in A$ right? I don't think I've seen an argument like this one before, its pretty cool.